# Disable Button For X Seconds After Page Load With Error Message If Clicked Too Early

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delay the functionality of a Submit button for a few seconds after a page loads. That part I have working.

Where I'm stuck is I'd like an "error" message to appear if the button is clicked while it's disabled. And then have the message disappear once the button is no longer disabled.

I'm having trouble getting this to work. My thought was to use a "click" event listener, which doesn't work while the button id disable -- which defeats the purpose.

Here's the html

```
<input type="submit" class="submitbtnstyle" id="submitbnid" value="Next"></input>
<div id="button-error"></div>
```

Here's the working disable/enable function...

```
window.onload = (submitDelay);

function submitDelay(){
    document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = true;
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = false;
    }, 3000);
    
}
```

And here's the error message that I haven't quite figured how to make work with the disable button and/or combine with the above script.

```
document.getElementById("submitbnid").addEventListener("click", ButtonError);

function ButtonError(){
        document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = 'Oops, Too Fast. Try Again in 2 seconds.';

        setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = '';
    }, 3000);
    
}
```

For reference, the purpose of this delay is because I have a hidden form field that dynamically updates the value after searching/finding an id in a first-party cookie that is set in the browser. There is a slight delay placed for this process as the cookie has to be first set prior to searching for and adding this id.

So perhaps a better strategy is not to arbitrarily disable the submit button for x seconds, but rather somehow check to see if the id is updated in the hidden field. But I'm not entirely sure how to go about that approach. So I'm resorting to a 3 second delay, which should not cause an issue for the majority of users.

```js
window.onload = (submitDelay);

function submitDelay() {
  document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = true;

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = false;
  }, 3000);

}

document.getElementById("submitbnid").addEventListener("click", ButtonError);

function ButtonError() {
  document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = 'Oops, Too Fast. Try Again in 2 seconds.';

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = '';
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="submitbtnstyle" id="submitbnid" value="Next"></input>
<div id="button-error"></div>
```

Edit: here is the hidden field that gets updated to a random letter/number string, where {clickid} is the default value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="clickid" value="{clickid}">
```

Comment: Let me get it clear, you want to disable the button for 3 seconds when the page is loaded, but also to be able to show an error message after clicking while it's disabled. Is that correct?

Comment: @HaoWu yes, that is correct. The button should still be visible while disabled, so looking to add that error message to let the user know to "try again in a few seconds" if they came to the site and hit submit rather fast (within those first 3 seconds).

Comment: *But I'm not entirely sure how to go about that approach.* - Why can you not just check the value of the input and see, if it is different from the default value?

Comment: @Geshode what you suggest is probably the better approach. I'm not very familiar with javascript, so will dig in the docs to try to figure that one out. Appreciate the tip.

Comment: Can you add code to the part that updates the hidden field, to also enable the button?

Answer (score 1):

Because disabled elements won't trigger any mouse events, this is a little bit finicky to achieve.

But it is still possible, here's a workaround:

1. Wrap your button in another element, such as this `<span>`

```html
<span id="button-wrapper">
  <input type="submit" class="submitbtnstyle" id="submitbnid" value="Next" />
</span>
```

2. Instead of adding the error click event to the button, adding it to the wrapper.

```js
document.getElementById("button-wrapper").addEventListener("click", ButtonError);
```

3. Make the button click-through when it's disabled using CSS, so the wrapper could receive the click event when the button is disabled.

```css
#submitbnid:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

4. 3 seconds after the page is loaded, remove the error click event from the wrapper when enabling the button

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("button-wrapper").removeEventListener("click", ButtonError);
}, 3000);
```

```js
window.onload = (submitDelay);

function submitDelay() {
  document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = true;

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("submitbnid").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("button-wrapper").removeEventListener("click", ButtonError);
  }, 3000);

}

document.getElementById("button-wrapper").addEventListener("click", ButtonError);

function ButtonError() {
  document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = 'Oops, Too Fast. Try Again in 2 seconds.';

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = '';
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#submitbnid:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="button-wrapper">
  <input type="submit" class="submitbtnstyle" id="submitbnid" value="Next" />
</span>
<div id="button-error"></div>
```

Comment: Or OP could just not disable the button and use a flag to know, if the button should show the alert or do the usual behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the wrapper approach previously before I posted here and couldn't get it to work. The `pointer-events: none;` css did the trick! Cheers!

Comment: @Geshode Maybe you're right. This approach avoids changing the fact that the button is physically "`disabled`" with some default disabled style and behavior attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Geshode advice, I did the following to check if the default value of the form field was changed. If not, then display message and prevent default behavior of submit button. Once a couple seconds passes after the error message, the button will work as normally and (I assume) will check again if the value has changed when the user hits Submit.

Thanks for the help and suggestions from all.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ 
  $rtclid = $('#zipform input[name=clickid]');
  $rtclid.data('default',$rtclid.val());
});

$('#zipform').submit(function(){
  $form = $(this).closest('form');
  $rtclid = $('input[name=clickid]', $form);
  if ($rtclid.val() === $rtclid.data('default')) {
     event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = 'Oops, Too Fast. Try Again in 2 Seconds.';
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('button-error').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('button-goodtogo').innerHTML = 'Ok, try now ';
    }, 3000);

  }
});
```

.

```
<input type="hidden" name="clickid" value="{clickid}" data-default="{clickid}">
<div id="button-error"></div><div id="button-goodtogo"></div>
```